# ng2-datepicker additional attributes usage

Tags: angular, ng2-datepicker

Can anyone help me in using additional attributes of [ng2-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker)?

I have tried:

```
<ng-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [options]="options" [isOpened]="true"></ng-datepicker>
```

I want to use the calendar of date picker in two ways in two different places.

1. Calendar has to be opened by default and should not hide on selection of date
2. vice-versa of the other(default working of ng2-datepicker)

Comment: And what exactly have you tried to achieve what you want?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to format your code so that it renders correctly. Can you please add some information on what does not work with your current approach? What do you expect to happened and what happens instead? Are there error messages? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: Look my answer here, it can help you out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170663/always-showing-the-calendar-from-datepicker-angular

Comment: did you tried my answer.Once you tried let me know.Perfect working.

Comment: @Monica Murugappan did you tried?.What happened?

Comment: did you used same code what iam maked stackblitz?. please follow same steps

Comment: What happened did you added that missing part?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some component for you using https://github.com/bleenco/ng2-datepicker this.

Install this depenencies lines,

date-fns

```
npm i date-fns
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns

ngx-slimscroll

```
npm install ngx-slimscroll
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slimscroll

Here is an source in stackblitz. **The sass property not supported in stackblitz. That's why output not displayed.You copy the ng-datepicker folder and past your project folder.**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agvjhm

Add this line in app.module.ts file,

```
import { NgDatepickerModule } from '../app/ng-datepicker/module/ng-datepicker.module';

imports: [   
    NgDatepickerModule,
],
```

app.html file,

```
<ng-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [isOpened]="true">

<ng-datepicker-default [(ngModel)]="date">
```

use some br tag between this two tags. Because opened default first tag. So it's occupy some spaces and covered second tag.

Working Perfect tested, Here is some screenshot,
[image]

let try this once and let me know.

**Edit:-**(Please Check)

app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { NgDatepickerModule } from './ng-datepicker/module/ng-datepicker.module';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgDatepickerModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ng-datepicker.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSlimScrollModule } from 'ngx-slimscroll';
import { NgDatepickerModifiedComponent } from '../ng-datepicker-modified/ng-datepicker-modified';
import { NgDatepickerDefaultComponent } from '../ng-datepicker-default/ng-datepicker-default';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ NgDatepickerModifiedComponent,NgDatepickerDefaultComponent ],
  imports: [ CommonModule, FormsModule, NgSlimScrollModule ],
  exports: [ NgDatepickerModifiedComponent,NgDatepickerDefaultComponent, CommonModule, FormsModule, NgSlimScrollModule ]
})
export class NgDatepickerModule { }
```

Iam added this lines only see.

Comment: hi,thanks for your help..there is an error while using ng-datepicker-default.
the code which i used is as follows:

        <ng-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [isOpened]="true"></ng-datepicker>
        <br>
        <ng-datepicker-default [(ngModel)]="date"></ng-datepicker-default>

Comment: and the error is:
compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'ng-datepicker-default' is not a known element:
1. If 'ng-datepicker-default' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng-datepicker-default' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("atepicker> -->
        <ng-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [isOpened]="true"></ng-datepicker>
        [ERROR ->]<ng-datepicker-default [(ngModel)]="date"></ng-datepicker-default>
      </div>

Comment: show your app.module.ts file. The error is occured during you have not imported  this module

Comment: please uninstall whay you installed before you don't need this. npm uninstall ng2-datepicker --save use this line

Comment: import {NgDatepickerModule} from '../ng-datepicker/module/ng-datepicker.module';

imports: [   
    NgDatepickerModule,
],

Comment: import { NgDatepickerModifiedComponent } from '../ng-datepicker-modified/ng-datepicker-modified';
import { NgDatepickerDefaultComponent } from '../ng-datepicker-default/ng-datepicker-default';

that module contain this lines?

Comment: No that module doesnot have these lines

Comment: that's the problem see my answer updated both modules

Comment: how to add

import { NgDatepickerModifiedComponent } from '../ng-datepicker-modified/ng-datepicker-modified';
import { NgDatepickerDefaultComponent } from '../ng-datepicker-default/ng-datepicker-default';

to ng-datepicker.module.ts

Comment: please see my answer iam updated completely.It's easy to understand

Comment: please copy and past all part of that module.

Comment: I did copy and paste but its giving error message as follows:

cannot find module '../ng-datepicker-default/ng-datepicker-default'.

Comment: It's a path problem please give correct actual path of an your app

Comment: is it not reqiured to have ng-datepicker-default in my app?should I install some npm packages for it?

Comment: no i did without any installation. Give your project structure and error screenshot

Comment: sorry i cant share screenshots as i am in secured network

Comment: I do my lot of help for you. I provide stackblitz also follow that example. That's all i have to help you.