# Always showing the calendar from datepicker - Angular

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar, angular-material2

I need to have the datepicker in Angular always visible. The calendar will be always visible without the dependency on the button (don't need to click on the button)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbzXz.png)

Source .html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `mat-calendar` for this:

```
<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="selectedDate = $event"></mat-calendar>
```

Comment: Thank, but can you post the better example? Like @Jacopo Sciampi ? I am new in angular and I get the error - ng: Identifier 'selectedDate' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations and element references do not contain such a member

Comment: @Alechandro here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-calendar

Comment: Thank you! I use your idea. But have one more problem. How i can add the three or four calendars next to each other

Comment: @Alechandro : This is a separte question and if you need more help you should post another question. This can be done in multiple ways. I've updated the stackblitz and used `angular/flex-layout` for this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `opened="true"` to the datepicker.

You can use code like this :

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker class="fixed-open" #picker opened="true"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysspzm?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html

Documentation : https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

[image: Taken from the documentation]

Answer (score -1):

you can using `opened="true"` for this.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker opened="true"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```